# Error when doing conditional checking of integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame that I want to do some operation on it. Basically what I try to achieve is that to access one of the column and use it as input value for other operations along the process.

The first thing I need to do is to access given column value and logically check. But even if that step my conditional falls a part!

here is the data and the function:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Marie', 'Kerie', np.nan], 
        'nationality': ['USA', 'USA', 'France', 'UK', 'UK'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'nationality', 'age'])

      first_name nationality  age
    0      Jason         USA   42
    1      Molly         USA   52
    2      Marie      France   36
    3      Kerie          UK   24
    4        NaN          UK   70

person_filter = ['Jason', 'Kerie','Marie']



def process_data(df):

    for pf in person_filter:

        df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['nationality'],keep='first')
        age=df1[df1.first_name==pf][['age']].astype(str).astype(int)

        print(age)
        print(age.dtypes)
        for ag in age:

            if ag < 30:

                #will use ag as input to do some special op

                print('you are young')
            else:
                #will use ag as input to do some special op

                print('you are older')




print(process_data(df))
```

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `ag` is the current column name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.   Your code is neither minimal nor executable as given.

Comment: @AlexandreB. yes I need  to access the `age` column values

Comment: @Prune my code is reproducible and minimal.

Comment: Your code fails on `pd` undefined in the second statement, and syntax errors thereafter from the embedded text.  The function and `for` are immaterial to the problem.  You neglected to include the full output -- and I expect that `print(age)` would clearly show where the problem lies, just as your first commenter pointed out.

Comment: @prune import pandas as pd

Comment: @Alexander: your code is still nowhere near minimal, please try to reduce it to a few lines that illustrate one occurrence of the error. We don't need the function definition line `def process_data(df):`. We don't need the loop on `for pf in person_filter:`, you could just pick 'Jason' for your MCVE example. So, the first line: `age = df1[df1.first_name=='Jason'][['age']].astype(str).astype(int)`. You don't even need the loop `for ag in age:` at all, it's unnecessary code, `ag` is a single value not a list or Series. And so on.

Comment: ...and you can illustrate the error just with `if '42' < 30:` The MCVE for this really is a one-liner. It didn't need a function, loops or even a dataframe. Please listen to the advice that people are trying to offer to help improve your experience asking questions on SO.

Comment: It's quite likely that you don't need a loop for this, as it stands your code is very unidiomatic. Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: @AMC@smci Thank you all for your suggestions. I would agree until some point how I should construct the minimal example. I spent some time about how can I best mimic the problem that I have in my real data and the functions. So I was really trying to undertstand how to access a value in a for loop. Since everyline of the code the data structure or datatype can change, most of the times I spend hours to find where are the bugs. So I tried my best! The solution to this example really explains deep to me how can improve my coding. I would definately take a look pandas docs and practice more.

Comment: @Alexander If you can describe the operation you’re trying to perform, the expected output, I can try to find and explain a more idiomatic solution tomorrow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `ag` variable is the **column name** and not the **value**. To get the values, just call the `.values` on the `age` variable:

```
age.values
```

In short, replace `for ag in age:` by `for ag in age.values:` and then select the first element from the list.

Here an example:

```
def process_data(df):
    for pf in person_filter:
        df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['nationality'],keep='first')
        age=df1[df1.first_name==pf][['age']].astype(str).astype(int)
        for ag in age.values:
            if ag[0] < 30:
                #will use ag as input to do some special op
                print('you are young ({} years)'.format(ag[0]))
            else:
                print("you are old ({} years)".format(ag[0]))
                #will use ag as input to do some special op

process_data(df)
# you are old(42 years)
# you are young(24 years)
# you are old(36 years)
```

Answer (score 2):

replace following line

```
for ag in age:
```

with

```
for ag in age.values:
```